# php integer value breaks whole controller "server setting"?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, php-ini

I have recently moved a working codeigniter project to a new server, a number of pages from the same controller were failing. I traced it down to this line

`$card['id'] = 00086;`  Breaks whole file

`$card['id'] = "00086";` is fine but casted as a string

`$card['id'] = (int)"00086";` works but why?

`$card['id'] = 86;` works but why?

is there a server setting that I'm not familiar with?
I'm not even in the function the line is in, its breaking everything after it.

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I really just want to know why so I can make the change to the server and not run into the same issue with another file... it was working on a previous server just fine

Answer (score 3):

This is because php tries to interpret the number as an octal number due to the leading zero. For example

```
$a = 08;
var_dump($a);
```

will throw error because `08` is not a valid octal number, but

```
$a = 07;
var_dump($a);
```

will not throw error because it is a valid octal number.

```
$a = 0071;
var_dump($a);
```

will produce `int(57)` because `71` in octal, which translates to `57` in decimal.

[documentation link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) says:

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use
>   hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary
>   notation precede the number with 0b.

By the way, `(int)"0086"` works because php first encounters `0086` as a string then casts it into integer so the number becomes `86` in this case. `$var = 86` works for straightforward reason, because it is a valid decimal number.